# Tweaking a Query - looking for duplicates within a certain day range

Tags: sql, vertica

I posted a question similar to this, and got an answer, but the answer isn't configurable - my fault I should have been more clear, so I'll try again.

I have a table where TABLENAME has the following information - OrderDate, OrderNumber, CustomerID, ProductSKU, ProductName exist. This table has lines for invoices. So an order will have a data line for every item in the order.

I want to know, which customers have ordered the same item, more than once, where the order is within 90 of any other order of that same product by that customer, after a specific date. Same product in the same order number do not count. The catch is that I want "more than once" to be configurable, so if I need to see 3 or more, or 4 or more I can adjust AND I want to see the counts. Here's the query I have so far, which I think gives me the items and the counts - but not the 90 day thing:

EDITED: I don't think the former version gave me the right counts

```
SELECT customerid, productsku, productname, count(distinct ordernumber) FROM tablename
WHERE orderdate >'2017-11-01'
GROUP BY customerid, productsku, productname
HAVING COUNT(distinct ordernumber) > 2
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and desired output?

Comment: post sample data, expected output and actual output

Comment: I've simplified the data because I can't really share it. If this isn't enough to go on, I understand. I'm not even sure how I would mock this up?

Comment: are your 90 day periods static or at least tied to values? I can see there being much more complextiy without. If I order on day 1, 89, and 110 all 3 orders are within 90 days of day 89 however they are not all within 90 days of each other. Am I returning 3 different totals (centering around each order), just taking the highest one? the first one?

Comment: @MarkD - they should be tied to the order dates between. What I am looking for is ordering the same item with a certain frequency. If I look at a years worth of orders - and they ordered something in january, then again in december, that's not really something significant, but if they ordered something every two months all year, then that's helpful. So I want to know if the order dates between same items are 90 days or less. The count i want, is for how many times they made an order for that item that fell within 90 days of any other order of that item.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this. it'll go back 90 days

```
declare @date date = '2017-11-01'

    SELECT customerid, productsku, productname, count(distinct ordernumber) FROM tablename
    WHERE orderdate >= dateadd(DD,-90,@date) and orderdate <= @date
    GROUP BY customerid, productsku, productname
    HAVING COUNT(distinct ordernumber) > 1
```

Comment: thanks for this! Let me make sure I understand - what you're doing is declaring a date - and saying that anyone who ordered the same product more than once within 90 days of the declared date will show up on the list correct?

To clarify, and I think this makes this request a lot more complex, what I need to try to do is find customers/items where the item was ordered within 90 days + or - from the date of any order of the same item. 

Put another way, and maybe I'm looking at this wrong. I want to identify customers who bought the same item more than 1 time in ANY span of 90 days

Comment: @Kyngfish this seems like a good application using Vertica pattern matching. You'll need to start with some qualification (i.e. 3 years back), order by order date, then specify the pattern of how to connect each of these orders. Decent documentation on the vertica site here: https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/AnalyzingData/EventSeriesPatternMatching.htm

Answer (score 0):

yes that is what I was doing in the first query. so this might be a really crappy way of doing it but without seeing any data it was kind of tough. this query shows gives you the order dates as well. hope it helps

```
WITH DupsWithin90Days (customerid,productsku,productname,orderdate,num)
as
(
select customerid,productsku,productname,orderdate ,count(*) num from (
SELECT X.customerid, X.productsku, X.productname,X.ORDERDATE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by x.customerid,x.orderdate order by x.orderdate) rownum
FROM
(
SELECT T1.customerid, T1.productsku, T1.productname,T1.ORDERDATE
FROM TABLENAME1 T1
) X
JOIN 
(
SELECT T2.customerid, T2.productsku, T2.productname,T2.ORDERDATE
FROM
TABLENAME1 T2 
) Y 
ON X.customerid = Y.customerid AND X.orderdate >= dateadd(DD,-90,Y.orderdate)
) dup
where rownum > 1
group by customerid,productsku,productname,orderdate
)

select customerid,productsku,productname,orderdate 
from DupsWithin90Days 
order by customerid ,orderdate desc
```